# Getting npm error : Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@12.2.17 while installing angular/fire module

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, dependencies, node-modules

Am installing angular/fire module to implement Firebase authentication, but when I try to install it by `npx ng add @angular/fire` it throws the following conflicting peer dependency error in terminal, which am not understanding as how to upgrade one angular/compiler module of version 12.2.17 to a version of 12.0.0 which apparently is also present in modules.

Following is the error am getting:

```
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/fire@7.6.1.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/fire@7.6.1 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-unit-test-helper@12.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@16.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"16.0.3" from @angular/compiler-cli@16.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.3" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.3" from @ngtools/webpack@16.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ngtools/webpack
npm ERR!       @ngtools/webpack@"16.0.3" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.0.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^16.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"^12" from angular-unit-test-helper@12.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-unit-test-helper
npm ERR!   dev angular-unit-test-helper@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@12.2.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"^12" from angular-unit-test-helper@12.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-unit-test-helper
npm ERR!     dev angular-unit-test-helper@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-27T17_11_02_874Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

Following is the package.lock.json file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ktgusk?file=package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from the version of the command

```js
npx ng add @angular/fire
```

is trying to use. Because the version is not specified it is trying to get the latest version for that package which includes peer dependencies for Angular 16.

Try it specifying the version for the package you want to install with:

```js
npx ng add @angular/fire@12
```